# Best way to change the color of my error text in PHP?

Tags: php, text

How can i change the properties such as the color and font of my php error text to the screen?

```
function output_errors($errors) {
    return '<ul><li>' . implode('</li><li>', $errors) . '</li></ul>';
}

if
 (empty($username) === true || empty($password) === true) {
    $errors[] = 'You need to enter a password and username!';
}
```

Comment: `<li style="color:red">`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use HTML tags with inline styles for the quickest method. For more consistency, apply classes to the wrapping HTML tags and define styles in a CSS class.

---

After seeing @Fred's edits, you might do something like this:

```
return '<ul style="color:red;"><li>' . implode ('</li><li>', $errors)  . '</li></ul>';
```

Comment: If this was your accepted answer, please click on the checkmark next to the answer to show that you accepted this answer. Thank you.